# Mean and Standard Deviation in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to calculate the Mean and the standard deviation in SQl for the NONUSBOXOFFICE column and i came up with this i just want to double check if its a correct way or not!

```
select to_char(avg(nonusboxoffice),'$999,999,990.00') As Average, 
to_char(stddev(nonusboxoffice),'$999,999,990.00') As Deviation
from boxofficemojo 
where nonusboxoffice <> 0;
```

Comment: Did you consider actually *trying it*?

Comment: yes I did but i am not sure that AVERAGE and MEAN is the same thing is SQL or not?

Comment: Is there something from the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) you don't understand?

Comment: Either your query is incorrect or your tags are incorrect.  MySQL does not have a `to_char()` function, for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your usage is correct, assuming your definition of "Mean" is the arithmetic mean, which is usually what is meant by "mean" in statistics.